# PHP can't find mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I've got the following markup and PHP. It's for a gallery - to upload and display images. I followed through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxmQ-qMuMTk) tutorial, but for some reason the mysqli_connect_db can't find the DB. what am I missing?

```html
<?php
include('upload.php');
?>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Choose File: <input type="file" name="file">
Title: <input type="text" name="nam">
<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

and the PHP:

```html
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Melvin","") or die ("could not connect to DB");
mysqli_select_db($con, "galerie") or die ("no database");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$location = 'uploads/';
$target = 'uploads/' .$name;

 if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location.$name)){
  
  echo "file uploaded";
  
  $nam = $_POST['nam'];
  $query = mysqli_query($con , "INSERT INTO images(img_name,img_title)VALUES('".$target."','$nam')");
  
 } else {
  
  echo "file not uploaded";
   
 }

}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT FROM images");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 
 echo "<img src=".$row['img_name']." &nbsp; class='addClass'>";
  
}

?>
```

Comment: don't output fixed/unchanging error messages. they're useless. have the DB *TELL* you why things failed: `or die(mysqli_eror($con))`. and note that you're simply ASSUMING nothing could ever go wrong with the queries, are simply assuming that uploads never fail, and are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: What exact message are you seeing?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you not insert or not view? This is incorrect `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT FROM images");` it should be `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images");`

Comment: show the mysqli error messages - see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. and display the error number ;-/

Comment: Thanks! So now it says: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'galerie'

Comment: after implementing all the suggested changes, i still only get the following message: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'galerie'. As I only see this message, I can't tell whether I can insert or not, I don't get to see the <form>, I only see this message!

Comment: imo, No, you know you can connect as you don't get that error message. So, you get the error about the ` 'galerie'` database for that user. So, set up a new connection - just for for that database? With username and password (both the same for your local host) and all privileges. Test it from an SQL IDE. Then tell PHP about it?

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan Vincent, with a new User it now works! If you repeat your comment as an answer I can mark it as the right answer! Thx again!

Comment: Glad you got it working - my `answer` was just a guess. It is what I do when I get similar errors :)

Comment: Please post what you did as an answer so that this question stops getting any more attention as you have a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Also, this is missing what you are selecting

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT FROM images");
```

Should be (add *):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images");
```

Comment: You're right about the `SELECT * FROM` part, @nerdlyist -- but OP is selecting the DB with `mysqli_select_db($con, "galerie") or die ("no database");` so that 4th parameter isn't needed, because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new user with all the rights in mySQL specifically for this database solved the problem for me.